# Dataframe consisting of factors vs real numbers

Tags: r

I am using the BNlearn package, and the error that comes up when I run a test is `Error in check.data(x) : 
  variables must be either all real numbers or all factors.`. My dataframe, `EMG`, contains two types of numeric values:

1) ~30000 columns of values, many of them being decimals (I believe these are interpreted as real numbers).

2) ~450000 columns of values that are either 0, 1, or 2. (I believe these are interpreted as factors).

How can I get R to believe that the values in class 2) are real numbers, not factors. Also, I might be approaching the error the wrong way.

The data consists of 129 rows. An example of the data is below.

```
9.758314     8.290852     0.03077250   0.353504     2        1
9.640181     8.581444     0.02144100   0.381118     0        0
8.898238     8.441256     0.01640670   0.574626     0        0
9.784328     8.406762     0.01525690   0.553795     1        1
11.017669    9.101037     0.01828330   0.489020     1        1
9.400396     8.073811     0.01897480   0.513596     0        0
```

In this example, I believe the first 4 columns are interpreted as real numbers, while the last two are interpreted as factors.

When I typed the function I am using (gs, part of the BNlearn package) into R, this is what I get back:

```
function (x, cluster = NULL, whitelist = NULL, blacklist = NULL, 
    test = NULL, alpha = 0.05, B = NULL, debug = FALSE, optimized = TRUE, 
    strict = FALSE, undirected = FALSE) 
{
    bnlearn(x = x, cluster = cluster, whitelist = whitelist, 
        blacklist = blacklist, test = test, alpha = alpha, B = B, 
        debug = debug, optimized = optimized, strict = strict, 
        undirected = undirected)
}
<environment: namespace:bnlearn>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using (& maybe even a reproducible example)?

Comment: How many rows do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
  matrix(as.numeric(as.matrix(EMG)),ncol=ncol(EMG),byrow=TRUE)
```

`as.matrix` will return a character matrix, `as.numeric` a numeric vector, and `matrix` to restore the original structure.

Comment: Looks like it works, I just used as.data.frame to convert the matrix back into the data frame form. Thanks